# Статика не отображается на сайте Django

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap, static

Сделал, вроде-бы, все как в курсе, но выдает ошибки

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'blog/static'),
]


<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/font-awesome.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.carousel.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.theme.default.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'responsive.css' %}">
```

[image: путь к статике]

Comment: Где какие ошибки? Как запущен и настроен веб-сервер?

Comment: GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/bootstrap.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)  вот такие ошибки для каждого css файла

Comment: DEBUG=True в настройках включен?

Comment: да .!.!.!.!.!,!

Comment: Приложение `blog` добавлено в INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: это не приложение, в папке blog лежат файлы settings, urls, asgi и тд. Приложение имеет другое название и оно добавлено в apps. На страницу все выводится как надо(текст), но статика не подключается

Comment: Значит перенесите статику в какое-нибудь приложение

Comment: все получилось, спасибо

Comment: А опции STATIC_ROOT и STATICFILES уберите. Опция STATICFILES вообще не существует, а опция STATIC_ROOT нужна только для работы команды collectstatic (эта команда копирует статику из всех приложений в адрес указанный в STATIC_ROOT) и не используется при раздаче статики веб-сервером